# Get information from different dict by dict name

Tags: python, django

I have a data/character_data.py:

```
CHARACTER_A = { 1: {"level": 1, "name":"Ann", "skill_level" : 1},
                2: {"level": 2, "name":"Tom", "skill_level" : 1}}
CHARACTER_B = { 1: {"level": 1, "name":"Kai", "skill_level" : 1},
                2: {"level": 2, "name":"Mel", "skill_level" : 1}}
```

In main.py, I can do this:

```
from data import character_data as character_data
print character_data.CHARACTER_A[1]["name"]
>>> output: Ann
print character_data.CHARACTER_B[2]["name"]
>>> output: Mel
```

How do I achieve this?

```
from data import character_data as character_data
character_type = "CHARACTER_A"
character_id = 1
print character_data.character_type[character_id]["name"]
>>> correct output should be: Ann
```

I get AttributeError when try use character_type as "CHARACTER_A".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
In [38]: from data import character_data as character_data

In [39]: character_type = "CHARACTER_A"

In [40]: character_id = 1

In [41]: getattr(character_data, character_type)[character_id]["name"]
Out[41]: 'Ann'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [locals()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals):

```
>>> from data.character_data import CHARACTER_A, CHARACTER_B
>>> character_id = 1
>>> character_type = "CHARACTER_A"
>>> locals()[character_type][character_id]["name"]
Ann
```

Though, think about merging `CHARACTER_A` and `CHARACTER_B` into one dict and access this dict instead of `locals()`.

Also, see [Dive into Python: locals and globals](http://www.diveintopython.net/html_processing/locals_and_globals.html).

Comment: using new dict should be best solution

Answer (score 1):

You need to structure your data properly.

```
characters = {}
characters['type_a'] = {1: {"level": 1, "name":"Ann", "skill_level" : 1},
                2: {"level": 2, "name":"Tom", "skill_level" : 1}}
characters['type_b'] = ...
```

Or, the better solution is to create your own "character" type, and use that instead:

```
class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, type, level, name, skill):
        self.type = type
        self.level = level
        self.name = name
        self.skill = skill

characters = []
characters.append(Character('A',1,'Ann',1))
characters.append(Character('A',2,'Tom',1))
characters.append(Character('B',2,'Kai',1)) # and so on
```

Then,

```
all_type_a = []
looking_for = 'A'
for i in characters:
   if i.type == looking_for:
      all_type_a.append(i)
```

Or, the shorter way:

```
all_type_a = [i for i in characters if i.type == looking_for]
```